# (complex variables)Let $n \in \mathbb N$ and $f: \mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ be an integer function...

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification, problem-solving

> Let $n \in \mathbb N$ and $f: \mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ be an integer function.

> a) Prove that $f$ is a polynomial in $z$ of degree $\le n$ if and only if $f^{(k)}(0) = 0$ for all $k \gt n$.

> b) Prove that if there are $M, R \gt 0$ such that $\vert f(z) \vert \le M \vert z \vert^n$ for $\vert r \vert \gt R$, then $ f$ is a polynomial of degree $\le n$.

a)$f = a_0 + a_1z + a_2z^2 + ... + a_nz^n$

$f^{(1)} = a_1 + 2a_2z + ... + na_nz^{n-1}$

$f^{(2)} = 2a_2 + ... + n(n-1)a_nz^{n-2}$

$f^{(n)} = n(n-1)(n-2)...a_n$

$k \gt n$

$f^{(k)} = n(n-1)(n-2)...0 = 0$

b) $f(z)=a_1z+a_2z^2$ and $f(iz)=ia_1z-a_2z^2$. Using triangle inequality:

$ \vert f(z)+f(iz)\vert \leq \vert f(z)\vert+\vert f(iz)\vert$

$\vert f(z)\vert +\vert f(iz)\vert \leq k\vert z \vert^2+k \vert iz \vert ^2=2k \vert z \vert^2$

That's what I managed to do so far. I think a) is ok, but b) is clearly incomplete.

Grateful for the attention.

Comment: What does "integer function" mean?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming "integer function" actually means [entire function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entire_function),

1. As $f$ is entire, $f(z) = \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}z^n$ for all $z$. If all but finitely many derivatives in $0$ are $0$, then the sum is actually finite, and $f$ is polynomial.
2. Cauchy integral formula says $$f^{(m)}(0) = \frac{m!}{2\pi i}\int\limits_{|z| = R}\frac{f(z)}{z^m}\,dz$$
   From this we get
   $$|f^{(m)}(0)| \leq \frac{m!}{2\pi} \int\limits_{|z| = R}\frac{M|z|^n}{R^m}\, dz = \frac{m!M}{R^{m - n}}$$
   Taking $R \to \infty$, we get that for $m > n$, $f^{(m)}(0) = 0$, and thus by first point, $f$ is polynomial.